# How many different ways can the ministers rearrange themselves fulfilling the below order?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The  King  of  Zyorg  has  a  cabinet  with N ministers  and  they  have  assembled  for  a meeting. The King enters the meeting chamber to find that the ministers have arranged themselves so that friends sit with friends.

The seats are numbered $1,... N$ and we refer to the minister sitting on the $i$th seat in this initial arrangement as $i$.  So, the initial arrangement is of the ministers is $(1,2,3,... N)$.

The King orders the ministers to rearrange themselves and finds that some of the friends have just exchanged seats.  The enraged King then orders that they must rearrange themselves  so  that  for  every $k < N$ the  set  of  ministers  sitting  in  the  first $k$ chairs DOES NOT consist only of the ministers $1,2,...k$.

He then wonders if this is possible at all and quickly convinces himself that this is so.Then he wonders how many different ways can they rearrange themselves fulfilling his order.

For  example,  suppose $N=  3$.   The  initial  arrangement  is  of  course  $(1,2,3)$.   If  they are arrange themselves as (2,1,3) this will violate the King’s order because for $k= 2$ the ministers in positions 1 up to 2 are{1,2}.  On the other hand the arrangement $(3,1,2)$ fulfills the requirement.  For $k= 1$ we have $\{3\}$,  for $k= 2$ we have $\{3,1\}$.  You can check that there are exactly 3 arrangements that comply with the King’s order.  They are :  $(2,3,1),(3,1,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$.  So, for $N = 3$ the answer to this problem is 3.

Your task is to write out the answers for 3 values of N.

(a) N= 5 (b) N= 6 (c) N= 7

**My Approach:**

Well I tried to solve for all the Ks, making all of the combinations for all the k(s), where for every after 1 this formula must be followed $((k+1)!)*(k+1)!))$ and then every value evaluated for k must be added. This worked perfectly for $N = 3, 4$ but not for any of the sub-questions asked.

Comment: You're new here, so you don't yet know.  You should never post unsearchable images of text or equations because the site's internal search mechanism cannot "read" such images, and find equivalent or identical problems.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: I am sorry, should I edit and add all of it as text?

Comment: .....yes.......  Look around the site to see how it is done.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have edited it, can you please look at it?

Comment: Yep... thanks.  (+1)

Comment: This seems to be a computing olympiad question? If so, how have you tried to approach this algorithmically?

Comment: yes it is from a computing olympiad, I looked up a few algorithmic techniques to solve this but I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: Did you try listing out all cases? $N=5, 6$ are still reasonable viable. With those values, try checking what OEIS lists, and see if that generates any ideas.

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with OEIS lists

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arbitrary permutation of $n$ ministers and let $k^*$ be the least number $k$ such that the rule:

> the set of ministers sitting in the first  chairs DOES NOT consist
> only of the ministers 1,2,....

breaks. Obviously the sequence of the first $k^*$ ministers is an allowed permutation of $k^*$ ministers.

Let the number of allowed permutations of $n$ ministers be $c_n$.

Then due to the above-mentioned reason the overall number of permutations will be:
$$
n!=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{k}(n-k)! ,
$$
where a single term in the r.h.s. counts the combinations which start with an allowed permutation of $k$ ministers followed by an arbitrary permutation of the remaining $n-k$ ones. From this we obtain the recurrence formula:
$$
c_1=1;\quad c_n=n!-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k(n-k)! ,
$$
which gives rise to the following sequence of $c_n$ starting with $n=1$:
$$
1,1,3,13,71,461,3447,\dots
$$